# Перечень, в именительном или родительном падеже?

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в родительном или именительном падеже должен быть представлен перечень:

"В пищевой и перерабатывающей промышленности планируется осуществление следующих крупных инвестиционных  проектов, реализуемых до 2020 года:

организации, ввода в действие и увеличения мощностей по забою скота в Закаменском, Селенгинском районах;
технического перевооружения молокоперерабатывающих предприятий;
технического перевооружения мощностей ОАО "Заудинский мелькомбинат" в целях переработки зерна, поставляемого местными сельхозпроизводителями, и производства комбикормов;
развития мощностей по производству колбасных изделий в ООО "Пиката", организациях потребкооперации и др.;
расширения производства кондитерских изделий в ЗАО "АМТА", ООО "Тарко";
технического перевооружения существующих мощностей предприятий хлебопекарной отрасли - ООО "Колос", ООО "Хлеб", организации потребкооперации.
Главное слово "осуществление" требует при себе родительного падежа, верно? Возникли сомнения...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное слово "осуществление" требует при себе родительного падежа - верно. Но родительный падеж там уже есть - "инвестиционных проектов". Дальше проекты должны перечисляться в именительном падеже. И список лучше оформить в виде списка:

> Запланировано осуществление следующих проектов:
>
> - ввод в строй мощностей;
> - техническое перевооружение;
> - и так далее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!